# How to change font and its size of a label on Navigation Bar - ios8 #swift

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift, ios8, osx-yosemite

Cannot find how to change font or its size of a Navigation Bar, And also there's no option in Attributes Inspector.

I am using OSX Yosemite Xcode and Programming language is Swift

Comment: In your question you should show some code that does not work, so that the answer can direct you to correct it. Moreover, it should express clearly which are the results of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class TestViewController: UIViewController {
    //
    @IBOutlet weak var myNavigationBar: UINavigationBar! // created with a ctrl+drag

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //
        self.myNavigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 24)!]    
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Simons. It works, But is there any chance of increasing the size of Navigation bar. I mean the Label and bar button items are disturbing Carrier signal, battery percentage and time. Is there any chance of solving this. Thanks again

Comment: I am not certain - but I believe that this would involve subclassing `UINavigationBar`. You would probably want to do some Googling - and then maybe formulate a new question if necessary. Explaining what you are trying to do. Also - you would want to try to find out whether changing the height of a `UINavigationBar` item is allowed or whether it would get you a rejection. I don't know the answer - certainly the Apple design guidelines do nothing to encourage it. And there may be a better way of designing a solution.